# Where did the Millennium Falcon learn to communicate?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

From [the script](https://web.archive.org/web/20111223111136/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/esb-script.shtml):

> THREEPIO: Sir, I don't know where your ship learned to communicate,
>   but it has the most peculiar dialect. I believe, sir, it says that the
>   power coupling on the negative axis has been polarized. I'm afraid
>   you'll have to replace it.

Is it ever explained what dialect the Millennium Falcon's computer had, or why it was so "peculiar"?

Comment: From wookiepedia; "The cobbled-together nature of the ship presented many problems throughout her smuggling days and during the Rebellion. Systems were barely held together and apparently had many incompatibilities, resulting in numerous malfunctions. C-3PO commented that he wasn't quite sure where the ship learned to communicate leaving open the possibility that the ship's computer uses slang and/or vulgar language, thus upsetting C-3PO's sensibilities..."

Comment: @Richard - unless there's explicit citing, that sounds more like the Wookiepedia authors describing what they see in the movie and rationalizing it.

Comment: @dvk - I agree. It makes sense but there's no canon confirmation, hence why I've also linked the owner's manual in the answer below.

Comment: I always thought it was "pulverized"... interesting! I guess I never understood it properly with C3PO accent.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is L3-37, Lando’s droid co-pilot.

[image: L3-37]

> She was damaged in the escape from Kessel (in *Solo*) and died. Han, Lando, and co. uploaded her core processor into the Falcon so they could use her navigational database to plot a shorter course for their escape.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! I assume this is from the new *Solo: A Star Wars Story* film? If so could you [edit] your answer to be clearer about this? Adding evidence always helps!

Comment: This is the (now) correct answer, but it is not answered particularly well.

Answer (score 27):

Within the film canon, there's no specific indication of the reason why the ship has a peculiar dialect other than its generally "cobbled-together" nature. On top of that, whenever we see the ship at rest it's invariably in a constant state of repair using a mix of parts sourced from wherever Han can get them cheapest.

The ultimate implication is, of course that because the ship has been owned by a series of *rough-and-ready smuggler types* (Lando and Han that we know of), that the ship's brain is much the same, built using a mixture of official and unofficial parts and periodically using vulgar language which we know C3PO finds offensive.

---

In the excellent (but not especially canonical) "[Millennium Falcon Owner's Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345533046)" we can see the problem more clearly;

[image: Millennium Falcon Owner's Manual - Computer]

Answer (score 13):

In the radio drama version of *[The Empire Strikes Back](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3U5E06ZlMZ4)*, Han states that the Millennium Falcon's particularly rude communications is a product of being crewed by himself and Chewbacca.

Beginning at 1:38:00 in the recording linked above:

> **THREEPIO:**  Oh dear, oh dear.  Where is Artoo when I need him?  What an incredible mess!

**HAN:**  How's it going on the hyperdrive Threepio?  Fixed yet?

> 

**THREEPIO:**  Captain, I don't know where the Falcon learned to communicate, but she has the most peculiar dialect.

> 

**HAN:**  Don't knock her.

> 

**THREEPIO:**  No, no, she's very intelligent, but she can be so rude at times.

> 

**HAN:**  Well, it comes from hanging around with me and Chewie.  You're liable to start doing it yourself.  What'd she say?