# How did Jabba kill Jedi "Back in the old days"?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jabba-the-hutt

From this question:

[In what adaptation of Return of the Jedi did Jabba brag about killing Jedi in the old days?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190895/in-what-adaptation-of-return-of-the-jedi-did-jabba-brag-about-killing-jedi-in-th)

We establish that Jabba did kill Jedi back in the old days (or at least claimed that he did).

But how? Jedi are pretty handy at fighting and can mind-control their way out of situations in the same way that Luke (a novice at that time) escaped from Jabba's palace.

Is there any evidence to show how Jabba managed to do this, or did he simply get away with lying about it?  I'm also willing to accept evidence showing that Jabba successfully ordered the deaths of one or more Jedi.

And yes, I'm somewhat aware of the irony that such a powerful group of beings somehow managed to completely die out through no fault of their own...

Comment: In "The Clone Wars", some bounty hunters employed by The Hutts did cause some trouble for the Jedi. Of course, he is exaggerating, as there is no one left alive to tell so.

Comment: He sat on 'em...

Answer (score 36):

In [issue 12](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_12:_Outlander,_Part_6) of the Legends comic series *Star Wars: Republic*, Jabba the Hutt's agent [Aurra Sing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurra_Sing/Legends) killed Jedi [Sharad Hett](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sharad_Hett). While Sing had personal reasons for killing Jedi, she was on Jabba's payroll and Jabba wanted the Jedi present dead as well, meaning it wouldn't be unreasonable to claim the kill for himself. This was around the time of *The Phantom Menace*, fitting the "when being a Jedi meant something" qualifier. The fact that Jabba had one Jedi killed and attempted to arrange the deaths of others means it isn't unlikely he made other successful attempts.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question of how Jabba killed the Jedi, as 1) it doesn't explain how Aurra Sing killed the Jedi and 2) Aurra Sing is not Jabba.

Comment: @MasonWheeler "I'm also willing to accept evidence showing that Jabba successfully ordered the deaths of one or more Jedi."

Comment: @MasonWheeler - a mobster boss kills people by ordering his henchmen to do the actual execution. That's a "how".

Answer (score 17):

Although it's quite possible Jabba was taking credit for kills made by anyone in his organization, it's very likely that Jabba personally killed a Jedi or two.

Much like earthworms, Hutts have a decentralized nervous system and can move amazingly fast for their size. They also have remarkable recuperative abilities, able to heal from most wounds given enough time. In the Legends continuity, Hutts were shown to survive extensive trauma to their bodies, including lightsaber wounds.

In addition, older Hutts have a hide so thick that most blasters can't cause much damage... and a Hutt can live up to a thousand years. They continue to grow larger and stronger until their death, and as we see in "Return of the Jedi" are immune to Jedi mind-tricks.

All in all, a Hutt is a formidable opponent... even for a Jedi Knight. Basically, Leia lucked out that Jabba - a 600-year-old Hutt - was susceptible to suffocation.

Comment: @Snow - At the moment, it comes from 20 years of reading Star Wars novels & comics. But, yes, I'll expand the answer later when I have time.

Comment: "it's very likely that Jabba personally killed a Jedi or two" You argument supports that idea that he could have, not that it's likely he actually did.

Comment: "Leia lucked out" -- I've seen somewhere a theory that this is probably one of the best examples in all the films showing that she has an intuitive ability to use the force, in this case allowing it to guide her to strike in a vulnerable area.  So perhaps not luck.

Comment: @Jules ["In my experience, there's no such thing as luck."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSNNav2eYwk)

Comment: Worth pointing out that there was a Hutt Jedi in Legacy Canon...[Beldorion the Splendid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Beldorion). Easily my favourite Jedi. Leia killed him in a lightsaber duel.

Comment: Where does the 600 figure come from? Asking because Lucas portrayed Jabba as much smaller when he redid New Hope. He said in the commentary it was due to logistical needs of the scene IRL, but in-universe due to age. It seems like it would be tough to argue he was fully mature at that time, if he'd just had a 10-year growth suprt that more than doubled his mass.

Comment: @T.E.D. - Jabba's age and birth year were given in "Star Wars: Everything You Need to Know". It came out in 2015, but I also know from one of the older reference books that Jabba was 80 years old when he started his criminal empire, and THAT was a good 500 years before Luke was born. I'll try to tweak up the answer this weekend.